# Simple site search django

Tags: django, python-3.x, search

I'm trying to create a simple search for products in the online store. I watched  tutorials and read questions here. I tried to do it. Nothing succeeded. What did I do wrong? 
view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.db.models import Q
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
from .models import Category, Product
# Product page
def ProductList(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        return Product.objects.filter(title_icontains=query)


    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'product/list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    })

def ProductDetail(request, id, slug):

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    return render(request, 'product/detail.html', {'product': product})


def ProductDetail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request, 'product/detail.html',
                  {'product': product,
                  'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})
```

product\list.html

```
 <form method="get" action="">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="search..." value="{{request.get.q}}"/>
              <input type="submit" value="search"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ProductList(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    query = request.GET.get('query') //as your input field name is query and not q
    if query:
        products = Product.objects.filter(title__icontains=query) // __ not _ 
        return render(request, 'product/list.html', {
        'products': products
    })

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
        return render(request, 'product/list.html', {
            'category': category,
            'categories': categories,
            'products': products
        })
```

change your view to this

Comment: This does not work. "Cannot resolve keyword 'title_icontains' into field. Choices are: available, category, category_id, created, description, id, image, name, order_items, price, slug, stock, updated". That was my fault. I fixed on "return Product.objects.filter(name=query)".  And new error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: what are you passing in the url?? can you show the url which you are processing

Comment: Okay.  urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', view.ProductList, name='ProductListByCategory'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', view.ProductDetail, name='ProductDetail'),
    url(r'^$', view.ProductList, name='ProductList'),
]

Comment: not this, means in the browser. what you passed when the error came

Comment: ValueError at /too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/?query=coffee
Django Version:  2.1.4
Exception Type:  ValueError
Exception Value:  too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Exception Location:  C:\Users\Anna\PycharmProjects\myshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in build_filter, line 1161

This?

Comment: Corrected all. Thanks for the help  :)